# Why should I look at the case one by one and not just use combination on this problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Out of a class of 8 boys and 4 girls, a group of 7 people is chosen at random.

Find the probability that the group of 7 includes at least 2 girls.

My solution:
Total ways: $12\choose7$=792
Group of 7 includes at least 2 girls: $4\choose2$ $\times {10\choose5}$ which will exceed the total ways.
The correct way of doing it is by looking at each of the cases. My question is, what did I not take to account in my solution? Why is it wrong?

Comment: You are multiply counting all the solutions with more than $2$ girls.  Specifically, given a good group with, say, exactly $3$ girls, there is no way to tell which $2$ of them formed the special pair you chose first.

Answer (score 1):

From reading all of the answers from this and other questions I've concluded an explanation, I'll divide it into steps, this is using my (incorrect) solution ${4\choose2
}\times {10\choose 5}$ :

1. When you choose 2 girls from 4 girls

Say we have chosen $g_1,g_2$

2. Choose the other 5 people from the 10 left

Say the other 5 people are $g_3,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$

Hence we'll have a group which is composed of $g_1,g_2, g_3,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$

However, say we have chosen $g_1,g_3$ and the other 5 people are $g_2,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$ giving us $g_1,g_3, g_2,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$ which is essentially the same thing  as $g_1,g_2, g_3,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$. That is what I missed.

Answer (score 0):

$\color{white}{\require{cancel}{3}}$

Think of it this way:

You know that there are a total of $792$ possible ways to choose $7$ people out of a group of $12$, and that there are $8$ boys and $4$ girls.

Now, what you need to do is $\binom{8}{6}+\binom{8}{5}+\binom{8}{4}$, which gives you the probability that there are at least $2$ girls can be represented as a sum as $$\sum_{k=0}^2 \binom{8}{6-k}$$$$=28+56+70$$$$=154\text{ total possible combinations including at least }2\text{ girls}$$Hope this helps!

Comment: Shouldn't the total number of combinations including at least two girls be ${8\choose 3}\cdot{4\choose 4} + {8\choose 4}\cdot{4\choose 3} + {8\choose 5}\cdot{4\choose 2} = 672$ as boys and girls can be chosen indepently of each other?

Comment: @CartesianBear I guess I didn't think about that, but yeah, I guess you'd be right :|